# Update multiple rows of data MsSQL in a single query with knex

Tags: sql-server, knex.js

I've read just about every result I could find on SO, but nothing seems to work, maybe this isn't possible?

I want to update a table of entities, with new positions, `x, y, o`

ex:

```
let updatedEntities = [{id:1, x:2, y:2, o:90}, {id:2, x:5, y:5, o:0}, {id:3, x:10, y:10, o:270}, {id:4, x:20, y:20, o:180}]
```

No idea what this would look like in SQL, or knex for that matter, something like...

`update (x, y, o) values([(2, 2, 90), (5, 5, 0), (10,10,270), (20,20,180)]) WHERE id (1, 2, 3, 4)`

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score -1):

Unlike insert, updating multiple lines in a single query is something that SQL does not support.

You need to create one update query for each set of values that you like to update.